# How do I find out what entitlements an app has?

Tags: applications, mac-appstore

Sandboxed apps have to declare their entitlements.  Of course, that doesn't do me any good if I can't tell what entitlements it declares.  A text editor that has entitlements for Core Location, Network Server, and my Address Book, without my knowledge, could be much worse than an unsandboxed app.

How can I see what entitlements an app has?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

After some more searching, I found a command-line answer:

```
codesign -d --entitlements - --xml /Applications/Whatever.app
```

This will print out an XML plist with values like:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
<true/>
```

For more information see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1798/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014167-CH1-IOS_STEPS

If anyone knows an easier/nicer way, though, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Also more documentation about that: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH2-SW1

Comment: On Mojave 10.14.4, the command above prints an extra 8 bytes at the start: `fade7171000000fb`, making the XML invalid. Any way to avoid that or strip it away?

Comment: `codesign -d --entitlements - <filepath> 2>&1 | LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C sed 's/^.*\<\?xml/\<\?xml/g' | grep "<.*>"`

Maybe there's another solution, but that's how I strip those bytes. But I don't think it's necessary: you can `codesign` an app by pointing to an entitlements xml, and macOS will ignore those bytes anyway.

Comment: Add a colon to omit those bytes: ```codesign -d --entitlements :- /Applications/Whatever.app/```

Comment: I used `jtool --ent /MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` @Ken

Comment: The `:-` part was the key to making this work (that man fails to mention), whatever it means.

Comment: I try to see where can an App write files on disk (let's say Safari.app). The entitlements are quite thick and complicated, and I couldn't see where is the app "Sandbox" defined, and its scope on disk. A hint please?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe There's now a `--xml` switch which is much clearer than the colon, which is now deprecated.