# How do I see where can a sandboxed Mac application write on my disk?

Tags: mac, safari, sandbox, macos

I know the app entitlements define its scope of access to resources. I already figured out how to get an app's entitlements, using the answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52675/how-do-i-find-out-what-entitlements-an-app-has)

For example, to see Safari's entitlements, I use the following command in Terminal:

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- /Applications/Safari.app/
```

However, I cannot find there any list of directories the app can use to write files, and no list of directories where it can't. I'm especially interested to know where does Safari store temporary mid-download files.

Please advise.

Comment: Safari doesn’t download the files, it calls `nsurlsessiond` so you don’t need to parse sandbox entitlements for this... [see this for a primer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205257/5472)

Comment: But nsurlsessiond needs its write-permissions from somewhere too, isn't it? when different apps use NSURLSession objects to download things - it doesn't mean they have all the same locations to which they can write. Plus - even if it is nsurlsessiond who does the work - where can I read its file-system permissions?

Answer (score 3):

Any sandboxed app always has full access to anywhere in its own sandbox. Safari's sandbox is

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question (well, very partially) I know for a fact, that Safari can write files in ~/Downloads for instance, and that it keeps partial downloads elsewhere --- not within the ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari My question is a bit more general. WHERE is it written - the list of file-system locations an app can access (fore read/write/delete etc.)